# What was Mary's operation?

Tags: downton-abbey

In S3E8 Mary and Matthew run into each other at a doctor's office about fertility. Mary tells Matthew that the problem was her and she had an operation to correct it.

What was Mary's issue and what operation did she have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was never revealed in either the show itself or by the show runners. This, of course, hasn't stopped people from speculating. This was back in the 1920's, the operation seemed small enough that anesthesia was not needed, and it required a period of abstinence. According to [this blog](http://blogs.babycenter.com/mom_stories/what-was-lady-marys-little-operation/) this narrows it down a bit to removing the hymen and removing tubal blockage. [This other article](http://trmbaby.com/fertility-medicine-and-downton-abbey/) forwards a few other ideas as well.

Comment: I guess that's that: unsatisfyingly unexplained.